# jQuery click on page to slide-up menu except on menu itself

Tags: jquery

I have a small currency selector menu that slides up & down on click and added further code so that it slides-up if there is a click outside of the menu. However, when the menu is clicked on it also triggers the slide-up too which I want to try and stop. I have tried various code alterations suggested on similar questions including experimenting with :not, but I just can't get it to work. Please could you point me in the right direction:

demo: https://bp202.betapark.co.uk/

```
var current = $(".currency select option:selected").val();

if (current == 1) {
    $(".current-currency span").html('&pound; GBP');
}
if (current == 2) {
    $(".current-currency span").html('&euro; EUR');
}
if (current == 5) {
    $(".current-currency span").html('&dollar; USD');
}

// *** Below is where I am struggling ***

$(".currency").click(function() {
    $(".currency ul").slideToggle("fast");
});

$(document).on("click", function(event){
    var $trigger = $(".currency");
    if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
        $(".currency ul").slideUp("fast");
    }            
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youy can use `stopPropagation()` method which stops event from bubbling up the DOM tree and triggering events.

```
$(".currency").click(function(e) {
  $(".currency ul").slideToggle("fast");
  // add this
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".currency ul, .currency ul *").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
});

jQuery(document).on("click", function() {
  $(".currency ul").slideUp("fast")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still can't get it to function correctly. I've applied the code, but when you click on one of the currencies within the drop-down it still slides-up and when you click on any area on the page outside of the drop-down it doesn't slide-up. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? I've updated the page with your code: https://bp202.betapark.co.uk/ - Thanks

Comment: I think I made a mistake. `stopPropagation()` should be applied to the list not the button. Anyway, I updated my code and tested it on your website. It is working fine.

Comment: Again many thanks for your help, but I've applied the code and now when you click on the drop-down it automatically scrolls straight back up again. You can see the updated effect here: https://bp202.betapark.co.uk/

Comment: I forgot to add `stopPropagation` to `.currency` click handler. I updated the code.

Comment: Perfect - thank-you so much for your time and help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to trigger slide-up when click the menu option You can try

```
$( event.target ).closest(".currency select")
```

like that

```
$(document).on("click", function(event){
    var closets = $( event.target ).closest(".currency select")
    if(closets.length) {
        return;
    }
    $(".currency ul").slideUp("fast");
});
```